# C# format of date issue

Tags: asp.net

**My problem:** I need to get date format as "mm/dd/yyyy"

**Scenario:**

I have declared DateBirth as nullable DateTime.

The value I get when I use:

```
AdvancedObj.DateBirth .Value.ToString()
```

is: **"13/03/2013 00:00:00"**

The value I get when I use

```
AdvancedObj.DateBirth .Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

is :**"03/13/2013 00:00:00"**//This is roughly correct but, I do not need 00:00:00

I have tried this as well, but the format is correct and value is incorrect.

```
AdvancedObj.DateBirth.Value.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-Us"))


 **"13/00/2013"**
```

Can anybody point me, what am I missing?

Comment: `mm` is minutes. You want `MM` for months.

Comment: When using a custom date format, there is no need for a Culture. The formatting wildcard for a double-digit month is actually an uppercase `"MM"`, thus: `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the right format string for months - it is `MM`. `mm` is for minutes:

```
AdvancedObj.DateBirth.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Also, order them correctly as above - if you want months before days, use `MM/dd/yyyy`, if the other way around, `dd/MM/yyyy`.

I suggest you take a good long read of [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I have not observed 'm' carefully in MSDN. Was trying for it for a hour!. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Month are 'M'. 'm' is for minutes.

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```